i18next refresh translation files does not work on docker
In our nextJs app we store the translation files in a @/locales/text/ folder. We configured as the following:
import { createInstance } from "i18next";
import resourcesToBackend from "i18next-resources-to-backend";

export default async function initTranslations(namespaces, locale, i18nInstance, resources) {
  locale = locale ?? DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
  namespaces = namespaces ?? i18nNamespaces;
  i18nInstance = i18nInstance || createInstance();

  i18nInstance.use(initReactI18next);

  if (!resources) {
    i18nInstance
      .use(
        resourcesToBackend(
          (language, namespace) => import(`@/locales/texts/${language}-${namespace}.json`),
        ),
      );
  }

  await i18nInstance.init(
    {
      lng: locale,
      resources: resources,
      fallbackLng: i18nConfig.defaultLocale,
      supportedLngs: i18nConfig.locales,
      defaultNS: "common",
      fallbackNS: "common",
      ns: namespaces,
    },
  );

  return {
    i18n: i18nInstance,
    resources: i18nInstance.services.resourceStore.data,
    t: i18nInstance.t,
  };
}

We have a nextJs API - and when we call it we download new .json files from azure and overwrite the files inside this folder.
When we run this nextJs app on developer pc with npm run dev, and call the API endpoint - these changes are automatically applied and the page refreshed with the new translations.
We build a docker from this nextJs app, where we build the nextJs app and start it like this:
npm run build
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js

We see that calling the API endpoint - the files are replaced inside the docker image, but the changes are cannot be seen on the website. Not after we added this code to the azure downloader (to the end):
const { i18n, t } = await initTranslations();
await i18n.reloadResources();

We are out of ideas what are the root causes. Two ideas remains:

these translation .json files are built into the webpack files, and nobody listens to this folder anymore, does not really care about the changes on the file system
the import(...) inside the resourcesToBackend() is the guilty one, which does not reflect to the file system changes.

None of the two options we can handle. Also - out of idea how to solve the problem. If anyone has a good idea, a suggestion - please! help! :)
Thanks in advance.

Appaerently I replaced the resourcesToBackend to i18next-fs-backend, was needed some changes to fix the path to the local .json files, but now seems the reloadResources() really refreshes the resource files. Now the question is: on browser side needs to press F5 to apply and see the new resources alive. How to force that?
